# Is the manifest overwritten on updates?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have to make some configuration settings specific to certain builds of my app, in the manifest.

These builds have same package name and code basis as the "normal" ones -> it's the same app. But I need these few little extras in the manifest.

It's clear that I can make that, just by creating 2 different builds with slightly different manifest file.

But: What will happen on app update? Are the manifest files overwritten, such that my extras will be removed?

I think this could not be the case, since I read some infos about special permissions for pre-installed apps. If the whole manifest was overwritten on updates, this would not work.

But I don't know how it works for other special informations in the manifest.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manifest is replaced when you update your app. This is how apps request or remove permissions, and add new Activities and Broadcast Receivers.

Certain pre installed apps get extra permission not only because of the manifest, but because they are installed in a separate folder on the device, which grants them more permissions.

When an app is updated, your manifest file is replaced.

Comment: But there are special permissions *available* to use in the manifest -> the programmer still has to add them manually. So there must be some mechanism to "keep" some of the attributes.

Comment: What special permissions are you talking about? Your app can *request* any permission. Certain permissions however are only granted to apps in /system/app, and not to normal apps

Comment: I think it's those permission for system apps. But probably they are usable for apps which will be installed *always* in /system/app, and not apps which can be either (pre)installed there, or downloaded normally from Google Play...

Answer (score 1):

Your primary question already being answered, I'll answer your secondary one.  The special manifest permissions for pre-installed applications are managed by the code signing process.  A manifest is allowed to use those permissions if and only if it is in a .apk file that's signed by the same key as the system build itself (e.g., if you're installing on a Samsung phone, it would have to be signed by Samsung's key, and so on).  So it's actually less about being pre-installed and more about being authorized by the device manufacturer.

Comment: Okay. this information is also valuable. But the reason I'm curious about those permissions is to see if there's any way to have a "custom" version of the manifest for certain apps. But I guess, in the case of these authorized pre-installs, the manifest will be *always* this way, because *all* the apps are preinstalled. So I have to find another solution...